# installation of nodejs returned a non-zero code: 1 with docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM         ubuntu:16.10

MAINTAINER   Fátima Alves

COPY         ./dist /myprogram/
WORKDIR      /myprogram


RUN          apt-get update          \
                                  && \
             apt-get install -y      \
               curl                  \
                                  && \
             curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - \
                                  && \
             apt-get install -y      \
               python-dev            \
               libxml2-dev           \
               libxslt1-dev
```

And no matter what i do, this message is appearing in the terminal:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm not finding anything related in google.

Thanks!

Comment: please apply a proper formatting to the multiline statements, before someone can actually read it, e.g. like this https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/11fc019b2be3ad51ba5d097b1857a099c4056213/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L7

Comment: Done @EugenMayer. Is it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running this yourself to see what the error is? Like so:

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.10
[...]
root@96117efa0948:/# apt-get update
[...]
root@96117efa0948:/# apt-get install -y curl
[...]
root@96117efa0948:/# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
[...]
## Your distribution, identified as "Ubuntu Yakkety Yak (development 
branch)", is a pre-release version of Ubuntu. NodeSource does not maintain 
official support for Ubuntu versions until they are formally released. You 
can try using the manual installation instructions available at 
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions and use the latest supported 
Ubuntu version name as the distribution identifier, although this is not 
guaranteed to work.
root@96117efa0948:/#
```

So basically that blurb is telling you that your version of Ubunutu isn't supported yet. Try changing your config file to use ubuntu:16.04 - or work out some other way to install node.

Comment: Oups... Question, what `-it` stands for?

Comment: `-i` is interactive, `-t` is terminal - basically allows you to act as if you're on a terminal inside the image. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/